# How can I use a text editor on a page summary field?

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

In Drupal 7 I have the WYSIWYG module installed which provides a configuration setting "Enable on summary fields" to allow the HTML editor to be used on summary fields.

The WYSIWYG module is not available on Drupal 9.  Is there a way to configure Drupal 9 to use an HTML editor (CKEditor or something else) to edit summary fields?

I have searched for solutions and I don't want to create a new, separate "summary" field.  Drupal already has a summary field that I am already using.

Comment: Create a separate summary field. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2671162#comment-11832318

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. This is an [active locus of work in Drupal Core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2671162).